# Automatic code signing: Which profiles am I using?

Tags: ios, xcode, codesign

I want to know which code signing identities and provisioning profiles I am actually using when I have an **Automatic** setup (see screenshot). What is the easiest way to determine this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result of one of Xcode's automatic choices is important to you, then you should probably *make the choice yourself* and **disable** the automatic feature.

Q: Why isn't Xcode showing you the profile it *would* choose?

A: Because it doesn't know yet.

It won't know until it has actually built and made all the decisions necessary to automatically choose a profile and then sign the app. The Xcode team haven't yet (and may never) condense that code down into a dry-run version that can show a tooltip in the build settings.

You *could* implement this feature by running a post build script to discover which choices were made for you, but see my first point.

Something like:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c "print :Name " /dev/stdin <<< $(security cms -D -i YourApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision)
```

although it would probably be safer to check the profile's `UUID`.

Despite the above FUD, the choices made in the build settings are a *little* less important these days as you have to explicitly choose a profile and re-sign the app when deploying AppStore, Enterprise and Ad Hoc builds. That said, if you have an automatic deployment system, it wouldn't be a terrible idea use a script to check that your outgoing binary has been signed with the correct identity and has the entitlements you expect.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation makes perfect sense